# Its possible to install tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 in the same server?

Tags: server, tomcat

I have Ubuntu 12.04 server. In this server tomcat 6 was installed by yum. It's running properly and I installed tomcat 7 binary package but I am not able to start the `tomcat 7` process. I am getting this error:

```
The BASEDIR environment variable is not defined
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

Comment: This probably solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125249/the-basedir-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install both on the same server, you just need to configure different ports for both the instances.